# c opengl: can i calculate normals in gpu? (CUDA)

Tags: cuda, gpu, indices, normals

I am trying to access last and next indices coordinates inside the kernel.

ex: int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

then pos[idx].x, pos[idx].y, pos[idx].z would give current coordinates of a point. but cannot access other two. I am trying to calculate the normals of the changing triangle in GPU level using CUDA.

Comment: Are you really trying to ask about how to manipulate an OpenGL vertex buffer object in CUDA?

Comment: What topology are you using? Are three consecutive vertices one triangle, or do you have a dedicated array of indices (where three consecutive *indices* are the indices of the vertices of one triangle)?

Comment: Are three consecutive vertices one triangle : No 
it is array of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How easily normals can be computed on the GPU depends on the mesh topology.

It is easy to compute normals for a mesh with **triangle-list topology**: Use one GPU thread per triangle. This results in highly regular reads and writes and will work for any valid configuration of blocks and threads in CUDA. Unfortunately, triangle-list topology isn't very useful (for starters, it will be flat-shaded unless some additional processing is employed).

It is [much] harder to compute normals for a mesh with **triangle-strip topology** (which is commonly used). The problem is that vertices are used in multiple triangles and therefore you must accumulate a [weighted] average for each vertex-normal by combining multiple triangle-normals. Using **one GPU thread per triangle** means that multiple vert-norms will be affected from multiple GPU threads "simultaneously". Alternatively, using **one GPU thread per vertex** means that a list of triangles that reference that vertex are needed, then the triangles need to be read (pairs of additional verts) so that the vert-norm can be computed... which is difficult, but not impossible.

Finally, if your model uses indexed vertices, this will impose an additional [semi-random] look-up which may cause problems. This problem can be addressed with spatial partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do idx+1, idx+2, the GPU has access to all the shared memory

For best efficency you have to be a little carefull about how you divide up the job into blocks/threads etc so that memory for nearby points is on the same core.

Comment: Thank yo for the reply... I thought the same. Unfortunately, idx+1 and idx+2 dose not carry the corresponding triangle coordinates. wondering whether there is any function call at least to access this or calculate new normals. I am passing simple VBO indices array.